# Why does accumulate in C++ have two templates defined

Tags: c++

Why does accumulate in C++ have two templates defined when the job can be done with just one template (the one with the `binaryOperation` and default value to sum)?
I am referring to the accumulate declaration from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/accumulate/

Comment: What should be the default value to `sum` in your opinion?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: `std::plus`?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate *"The first version uses operator+ to sum up the elements, the second version uses the given binary function op"*

Comment: As it is already said in one of the answers, it is a matter of taste. You have an article about it here https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/08/07/should-i-use-overloads-or-default-parameters/

Answer (score 9):

Because that's how the standard has been specified.

It is often a matter of taste whether to use an overload or a default argument. In this case, overload was chosen (by committee, by Alexander Stepanov, or by whoever happened to be responsible for the choice).

Default values are more limited than overloads. For example, you can have a function pointer `T (*)(InputIterator, InputIterator, T)` pointing to the first overload, which would not be possible if there was only one function (template) with 4 arguments. This flexibility can be used as an argument for using overloads rather than default arguments when possible.

Comment: This. And I'm not sure all the machinery was there to make only one overload in 98. In C++14 it's easy though.

Comment: @StoryTeller if you had a single declaration `template <typename It, typename T, typename Op = plus<>> It accumulate(It, It, T, Op = {})` don't you have issues with non-default-constructible operations? Or does the fact that it isn't using the default parameter make it OK?

Comment: @Caleth A default function argument that is not used is ignored entirely. So using that declaration, `accumulate(c.begin(), c.end(), 0, [](auto& x, auto& y) { return x+y*y; })` would remain valid, even though a closure type cannot be default-initialized.

Comment: @Caleth Well "ignored entirely" is a simplification.  More exactly, every default argument must always have valid syntax, and for a non-template function, the semantics of a default argument and initializing the function parameter with that expression must be valid even if the argument is never used. But for a template function, each default argument is considered to be separately instantiated from the function declaration itself and any other default arguments, and only if that default argument is actually used.

Answer (score 6):

It's true you would get mostly the same behavior from a single template like

```
template <class InputIt, class T, class BinaryOperation = std::plus<>>
accumulate(InputIt first, InputIt last, T init, BinaryOperation op = {});
```

But note that in earlier versions of C++, this would be difficult or impossible:

- Prior to C++11, a function template could not have default template arguments.
- Prior to C++14, `std::plus<>` (which is the same as `std::plus<void>`) was not valid: the class template could only be instantiated with one specific argument type.
- The `accumulate` template is even older than the first C++ Standard of 1998: it goes back to the SGI STL library. At that time, compiler support for templates was rather inconsistent, so it was advisable to keep templates as simple as possible.

So the original two declarations were kept. As noted in [bobah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52442791/459640), combining them into one declaration could break existing code, since for example code might be using a function pointer to an instantiation of the three-argument version (and function pointers cannot represent a default function argument, whether the function is from a template or not).

Sometimes the Standard library will add additional overloads to an existing function, but usually only for a specific purpose that would improve the interface, and when possible without breaking old code.  There hasn't been any such reason for `std::accumulate`.

(But note member functions in the standard library can change more often than non-member functions like `std::accumulate`. The Standard gives implementations permission to declare member functions with different overloads, default arguments, etc. than specified as long as the effects are as described. This means it's generally a bad idea to take pointers to member functions to standard library class members, or otherwise assume very specific declarations, in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

The motivtion for the 2 functions is the same reason that we have both a `copy` and a `transform` function, to give the coder the flexability to apply a function on a per element basis. But perhaps some real world code would be helpful in understanding where this would be used. I've used both these snipits professionally in coding:

The 1<sup>st</sup> instance of accumulate can be used to sum the elements of a range. For example, given `const int input[] = { 13, 42 }` I can do this to get the sum of all elements in `input`:

```
accumulate(cbegin(input), cend(input), 0) /* Returns 55 */
```

I personally most commonly use the 2<sup>nd</sup> instance to generate `string`s (because it's the closest thing [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) has to a [`join`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html)) but it can also be used when special preprocessing is needed before the element is added. For example:

```
accumulate(next(cbegin(input)), cend(input), to_string(front(input)), [](const auto& current_sum, const auto i){ return current_sum + ", " + to_string(i); }) /* Returns "13, 42"s */
```

---

It's worth noting [P0616R0](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0616r0.pdf) when considering my use of the 2<sup>nd</sup> function. This proposal has been accepted into [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) and will move rather than copy the first parameter to `accumulate`'s functor, which, "Can lead to massive improvements (particularly, it
means accumulating `string`s is linear rather than quadratic)."